# How to integrate 3rd party session into my website in iframe?

Tags: iframe

My website integrates some 3rd party web pages using frame. Both my website and 3rd party website maintain own session separately. I am wondering if it is possible to sync them so that my session will not be expired when user only click buttons in iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need some code on the parent window, that refreshes the parent window every x minutes. It would kill whatever the client is doing in the iframe though.

Or the parent window could do ajax requests to the server every x minutes to keep the session alive.

Comment: will it provide user friendly experience. I suppose browser status bar will display the refresh action?